# SQL getting monthly totals from table

Tags: php, sql

I have a table with prices, date as a timestamp, the month of entry and the year of entry.

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Price | Date | Month | Year |
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
9.00  |343345|   2   | 2013 |
3.00  |343445|   2   | 2013 |
4.00  |343245|   1   | 2013 |
1.00  |342245|   1   | 2013 |
5.00  |333355|   12  | 2012 |
```

So far I have this to list the monthly price totals, the problem is GROUP BY re-sorts the results so that it goes month 1, month 12 then month 2 where as I need the results to descend from the current month, month-by-month.

```
"SELECT month,SUM(price), FROM table  GROUP BY month ORDER BY date DESC "
```

I'm using PHP if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your date field is not stored as a datetime.  Instead of ordering by it, order by your year and month fields instead (I presume you want to group by both of those fields).

```
SELECT year,month,SUM(price)
FROM table 
GROUP BY year,month 
ORDER BY year DESC, month DESC
```

If the year and/or month are stored as varchar, then cast them -- I suspect those are stored as integers though:

Answer (score 1):

It's treating your month as text instead of numeric. Cast it as an integer and it'll sort properly.

```
SELECT CAST(Month as int) as Month, SUM(PRICE), FROM table Group by month ORDER BY CAST(MONTH as int) desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast your month to INT data type:

```
SELECT month,SUM(price), SUM(price), FROM table GROUP BY month ORDER BY cast(month as UNSIGNED) DESC
```

More: [CAST](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I solved it by adding another column with 'date' type and convert all the different fields in dates. Then you can make selects within time range.